# How to forbid downcast from base to derived class in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, type-conversion, downcast

Is there a way to deny downcast of *Base* to *Derived* when *Base* is holding an instance of *Derived*? By default it's allowed.

```vb
Public Class Base
End Class
Public Class Derived
    Inherits Base
End Class

Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        TakesOnlyBase(New Derived)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub TakesOnlyBase(ByVal b As Base) 'Not allowed to make changes in Derived part on the instance
        Dim d As Derived = CType(b, Derived) 'it works since the variable `b` is holding an instance of Derived. How to forbid this cast?
        '...
    End Sub
End Class
```

The easiest way would be implement conversion function in *Derived* and just throw an exception.

```vb
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal b As Base) As Derived 'Compiler error: Conversion operators cannot convert from a base type.
    Throw New System.Exception("Not allowed")
End Operator
```

But conversion from a base type is not allowed. Any other possibilities to override default conversion?

Any other solutions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: that's the *power* of casts (... and it comes with great responsibility ;) ) ... so no I don't think there is a way (other then reflecting/throwing runtime exceptions) to stop the compiler from accepting those - you have to look outside of most OOP languages (and .NET is 100% mainstream) if you want type-saftey

Comment: Then it sounds like you don't really want an inheritance relationship - maybe look at just having the `Base` class and some kind of encapsulation/factories to allow creation of a "`Base` that has `Derived` behaviour".

Comment: @Carsten Catching a conversion call in runtime will be acceptable solution. Unfortunately overriding CType from base type is not allowed so what's else? Thanks.  PS Can't agree, I don't think outside OOP is stronger type safety.

Comment: @Damien Base and Derived behaves very similar and have a lot of common code. Derived adds some additional functionality. Breaking the inheritance will produce double code which would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Perhaps check [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx). (.NET 4.0+) I do not have practical experience with them yet (I am at 3.5), but it is possible that besides runtime checking, you could be able to implement some static checks, I quote: `• Static verification: The static checker can decide whether there are any contract violations without running the program. It checks for implicit contracts, such as null dereferences and array bounds, and explicit contracts.` Focus on preconditions (`Requires`)

Comment: It won't double the code if you *remove* `Derived`, just have a single class containing the code, but then use some *other* mechanism to achieve the different runtime behaviours. That's what I was trying to suggest.